# Cannot import protobuf in conda env even though it's installed

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, conda

on Ubuntu 20.04 and I can't import `protobuf` :

```
(r-torch) brucezepplin@brucezepplin-HP-ProBook-440-G7:~$ conda list | grep protobuf
libprotobuf               3.17.2               h4ff587b_1  
protobuf                  3.17.2           py39h295c915_0  
(r-torch) brucezepplin@brucezepplin-HP-ProBook-440-G7:~$ python
Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 13:09:58) 
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import protobuf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'protobuf'
```

any ideas?

Comment: looks to me like the imports are `import google.protobuf`, `from google.protobuf import ...` etc.

Comment: this works - please put as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python package for protobuf has a package structure that uses `google` as an root prefix:

```
import google.protobuf
from google.protobuf import <pkg-name>
```